# Can MySQL Enterprise Backup perform partial backup/restore of views?

Tags: mysql

I'm not able to backup and restore views using partial backup/restore (with tts) using MEB 3.12 with MySQL 5.6.28. Is this by design?

Have been searching for quite a while but not able to find helpful information on how views, triggers and stored functions are handled by MEB. Any information on the above subject is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. what is MySQL version(x,y,z)?

Comment: Views are based on the underlying tables - back those up and the views "come along for the ride"!

Comment: @Vérace Unfortunately that's not what's happening in my case. The .frm files associated with the Innodb tables are not being backed up at all thus leading to the question I have.

Comment: You are saying that you have a `VIEW` which returns different results  from the underlying tables? OK - show us real results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more searching, the answer was finally found in Oracle Doc ID 1393056.1. https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1393056.1 Link may be paywalled.

> Only includes InnoDB tables. Tables using all other storage engines as well as views will not be included in the backup.

To make matter worse, --only-known-file-types options of MEB is not compatible with the --tts options.

It looks like the only way is to perform another additional mysqldump just for the views for partial backup.

Answer (score 0):

As per MySQL documentation [here](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/backup/features.html) you can "partial" Restore of particular tables or [tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-tablespace.html).

For your further ref [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/8.0/en/backup-partial-options.html) and [here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/general-tablespaces-in-mysql-5-7-details-and-tips/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what MySQL hot backup does is, it copies all data files from data dir to backup folder of a particular snap.

Instead of using mysqlhotbackup, you can use mysqldump for taking backup of trigger, views & routines. (If restorating this dataobjects are concern ).

```
mysqldump --single-transaction  --set-gtid-purged=OFF   --force --routines --triggers -h 192.168.XX.XX --no-data  --no-create-db  -u user -p --all-databases --lock-tables=false > backup.sql
```